# Can a monk use Dirty Fighting with Flurry of Blows?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, monk

I am looking to start a gnome monk character. Eventually, I would like to turn him into a Drunken Monk at a later level, after I obtain the necessary monk skills and feats. As part of the role-play aspect and to start his decent I was thinking about taking the Dirty Fighting feat at level 3.

The big question is, though, does Dirty Fighting stack with Flurry of Blows?
For example, I decide to attack a monster's eyes, toes, ears, groin, etc. and land both unarmed hits with flurry: **do I add the additional d4 to both hits or just one?**

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! Please take the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you get a chance. You don't need to put salutations, apologies, or thanks in your questions here. Just stick to asking what you need to know and try to keep the question as on-topic as possible. If you are concerned that a question has been asked before, you should search the site before asking to see if an answer is already available. (In this case, the question has not been asked before)

Comment: Even better: if you're concerned that a question has been asked before, do your research but don't worry too much. In that cas the question will be marked as a duplicate and you will get linked to the exisitng answers.

Answer (score 3):

The feat Dirty Fighting (originally *Sword and Fist* 6 but, later, *Dragon* #303 28, and [free here](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ch/20010402a)) as its benefit says, "As a full attack action, you may make a single melee attack that deals an additional +1d4 points of damage." Thus the benefit of Dirty Fighting limits its use to a lone attack taken as a full attack action; there's no way to mix the benefit of Dirty Fighting with [flurry of blows](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monk.html#monk-flurry-of-blows) as flurry of blows *also* takes a full attack action. One must pick *either* to fight dirty *or* to flurry.

That's okay, though, because the feat is terrible. Attempts were made to rehabilitate the feat by making it a short feat chain with the feat Improved Dirty Fighting (*Dragon* #303 30) or a different version of Improved Dirty Fighting (*SF* errata 2-3); neither of those feats works with flurry of blows, either, both still requiring a full attack action.

I understand that the goal might be something role-playing appropriate—and I *totally* understand that a drunken gnome fighting dirty could be hilarious—, but that can instead be the player describing his character's actions. You don't need to take a feat to say you headbutt the bad guy in the groin, and no one should take the feat Dirty Fighting.

Comment: Even the *Sword and Fist* errata admits the feat Dirty Fighting is “not a great option for high-level characters.” It's understating the case.

Comment: In the past we just did it as one extra 1d4 on one or more successful hits in a FoB.  Even then, it doesn't  really stack up to Weapon Specialization.  But it also didn't require a FIghter dip.